# Run Excel Macro at Certain Time

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set up my code to run a macro daily at 4am. As a testcase I wanted to check if it would run a test macro. I set it to run at 4:40pm, but it does not run at that time period (don't get a msgbox). I would really appreciate some advice on how to get it working so I can proceed with the actual running of the 4am macro.

Code:

```
Sub RunDailyProcess()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:40:00"), "TestMacro"

End Sub


Sub TestMacro()

    MsgBox "it works!"

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this code, in a module?

Comment: You need to include the date in the scheduled time.  Try Today() + TimeValue(...

Answer (score 1):

It can be done **one of two ways**.

**One** would be through *windows task scheduler*. Where you will set up a task to run Excel.exe yourfile.xlsm. Then bind your macro to the workbook "WorkBook_Open" event, with a check on current time.

Go to Task Scheduler, on the right click on "Create Basic Task...". Give the task a name and click next. Select a trigger (Daily in the case you mentioned here) and click next. Set the time and recurrence period and click next. In the Action, select "Start a program" and click next. In the Program/script text box browse for your Excel file and click next (leave the other text boxes empty). Click on Finish. I just tried this on my PC now, and it works.

**See** [Starting excel file with task scheduler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ce659a72-88e1-448b-8b45-ff2cb4ba9da8/starting-excel-file-with-task-scheduler)
 **See** [Task scheduler + VB script to auto open excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/302970-task-scheduler-vbulletin-script-auto-open-excel.html)

***Or***

Use the **code**:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("04:40:00"), "MyMacro"
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
    Dim rtn As Integer
    rtn = MsgBox("Good to Go!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "GTG")
End Sub
```

Things to keep in mind if you use the code:
You will need to make sure that excel remains open for the Application.OnTime to work, Excel will not be frozen/tied up. Putting it in the workbook open event, or something like that, to automatically have it run.

Either way:
Ensure your macro setting is enabled at all times because this will ensure that every time your workbook opens, the macro runs without any notification or confirmation.
**To do this**:
Excel Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings (Button) > Macro Settings > Enable All macros > OK

Comment: The second way works well for me, but make sure the sub `Workbook_Open()` goes into the ThisWorkbook object and the sub `MyMacro` goes into a Module.