# Automatically fill cell with a set value on specific calendar day and time

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automatically fill in a cell with a pre-set value on a specific calendar day and time.
Example:
On the 2023-03-01 at 08:00 I want the name 'John Doe' to be filled in cell A1 in excel file. How to go about this. Is it macro that is needed or are there other ways as well?

Edit: the Notebook will be closed down and its opened in a browser (if that even matters..). However, it will be opened on the date Im thinking of auto-filling text in a cell or two. One cell being a must, two cells being a bonus addition to my question.

Comment: This may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887189/run-excel-macro-at-certain-time

Comment: The workbook is always open?  If Yes you could use `OnTime` as suggested, if No othen you'd needto explain a little more about your exact use case.  There's only one value to be filled in?  If multiple values, where do the date/times and values come from?   Simplest approach would be to use a formula like `=IF(NOW()>DATE(2023,3,1)+TIME(8,0,0),"John Doe","")`

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, sorry. Im not that versed in Excel so my information was lacking. I've updated my question with an Edit answereing your question.

Comment: You can use a formula if the only requirement is that the name appear in (eg) A1 after a set date/time.

Comment: Using the same thread to ask this: Can a IF or VLOOKUP be used somehow to fill a cell based on the IF function you gave me? Say I want to populate A1 but I cant put in you IF answer in A1. But I can put DAX code in any other cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula:

```
=IF(NOW()>DATE(2023,3,1)+TIME(8,0,0),"John Doe","")
```